# Passing a class attribute to another form and then editing its values

Tags: java, swing, class, reference

Say I have two JFrame forms: `StaffListMenu` and `LeaveDetailsMenu`.

Within the `StaffListMenu` class I have an attribute called `staff` which is an ArrayList of all the staff members currently on the system. I would like to open the `LeaveDetailsMenu` form on a button click, and pass the `staff` attribute to the `LeaveDetailsMenu` class. To my knowledge I would do it like this:

```
private void btnLeaveDetailsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    LeaveDetailsMenu leaveDetailsForm = new LeaveDetailsMenu(staff);
    leaveDetailsForm.setVisible(true);
}
```

Now, I would like to call some methods and reassign some elements in the `staff` ArrayList from the `leaveDetailsMenu` class. If I do this, would the changes be reflected in the `staff` attribute of the `StaffListMenu` class?

I read that Java doesn't pass by reference (like C# can do, the only other language I have used for desktop applications), instead it passes a pointer to the memory location of `staff`. Going by that logic, it should make changes to the attribute in the `StaffListMenu` class, right?

Also, kind of a two part question, is there a way I can recognise in my `StaffListMenu` class when the `LeaveDetailsMenu` form is closed? Like a callback?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it should make changes to the attribute in the StaffListMenu class,
>   right?

yes. youre passing the ArrayList object (technically, youre passing by value the value of the ArrayList's address in memory) so any changes made to the object inside the call will be visible outside it.

> is there a way I can recognise in my StaffListMenu class when the
>   LeaveDetailsMenu form is closed?

yes. take a look at [Window.addWindowListener(WindowListener l)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#addWindowListener%28java.awt.event.WindowListener%29) (which JFrame inherits). you provide a listener and you can be notified of window close events.

Comment: You could also use a modal JDialog instead of a JFrame, which will block the calling code until the dialog is closed